# Howto configure autofs to work with usbsticks formatted with differend filesystems

Tags: mount, ext4, automounting, autofs, fat

I have some USB-sticks using `fat32` as filesystem and others using `ext4`. Now I want to configure [`autofs`](http://www.autofs.org/) to mount the sticks automatically.

To make sure that the user can write to `fat32` sticks I use the `umask` option in my `/etc/auto.misc` file. However (according to the mount man page), this option is not available for `ext4` file systems and when I try to automount an `ext4` stick this way I get an error message (via `dmesg | tail`) which tells me that `umask` is an unrecognized mount option and the mount operation fails. If I omit the `umask` option, the `ext4` stick works as expected but also as expected the `fat32` stick is only writable by `root`.

Is there any way to make `autofs` work for both types of sticks?

Is it possible to use somehow an `if` condition to decide whether to mount it with `umask` or not?

I studied the mount man page to solve the problem and discovered the mount parameter `-s` (sloppy), but I don't know how to apply this for autofs and it did not even work with normal mount command and umask (`mount -s -o umask=000 /dev/sdb1 /media/mymountpoint`).

As expected: same problem with `utf8` mount option.